# Dynamically create a class inherited from neomodel.StructuredNode

Tags: python, relationship, knowledge-graph, neomodel, dynamic-class-creation

Python's library *neomodel* provides the ability to define a relationship with a class that hasn't been defined yet, by using its name as string, which works fine as follows:

```
from neomodel import StructuredNode, RelationshipTo
# if Foo is already defined
class Bar (structuredNode):
    rel = RelationshipTo(Foo, 'REL')
# if Foo isn't defined
class Bar(StructuredNode):
    rel = RelationshipTo('Foo', 'REL')
```

I want to create a class in the **runtime** and provide it with the attribute *RelationshipTo*, which should make a relationship with **undefined** yet class, so I did:

```
Bar = type('Bar', (StructuredNode,), {'rel': RelationshipTo('Foo', 'REL')})
```

In some point in the runtime later, I define Foo:

```
Foo = type('Foo', (StructuredNode,), {})
```

Now if I want to use the class I've just made:

```
bar = Bar()
```

The next error still pops up as if I haven't defined Foo:

> AttributeError: module '_pydevd_bundle.pydevd_exec2' has no attribute
> 'Foo'

**Note:** This error doesn't appear if I at least define Bar statically (not in the runtime)

Would someone explain why that happens and how to define them properly in **runtime**, please?
I appreciate any help!

Comment: have you tried to inspect the attributes of `Bar`? `print(Bar.rel)` gives an error? Adding the relation, always at runtime, but in another moment i.e after `Foo = ...`?

Comment: Thanks for replying! `Bar.rel` doesn't give any error, but gives `<neomodel.relationship_manager.RelationshipDefinition object at 0x05DD4BC8>`. Adding the relation afterwards does give the error. Actually, I tried even defining the Foo class before Bar, and still gives the error. It seems that it can't figure out that this Foo class is the same that has relationship with Bar. How can I call it more specifically, known that when I call `Foo` returns `<class 'neomodel.core.Foo'>` , using which as a parameter for RelationshipTo doesn't change anything